# If two matrices have the same characteristic polynomials, determinant and trace, are they similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

If two $n \times n$ matrices have the same characteristic polynomials, determinant and trace, are they similar, EVEN if ($ \lnot \#Spec= 0$)?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. 
Take the identity matrix and the matrix $$a_{11}=a_{12}=a_{22}=1, a_{21}=0.$$